# How do I get my purchsed bitcoins from a old bitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet.dat

I had to refresh my computer do to updates and all my installed software such as Bitcoin wallet was gone after the process. I did back up my wallet almost everyday and also I did it on a external hard-drive, but when I re-install the Bitcoin wallet from bitcoin.org it give me a new receiving address and even if I have all back -up data and my previous receiving bit coin wallet where all my bit coins I have purchased were I do not know why is it not showing it in my new wallet. I have tried to recover and open my back up wallet files but it does not show my Bitcoins. Please help.

I did watch the recovery do to a failed hard drive but I can not access the files and I do not know how to get my Bitcoins from my old receiving wallet which I backed up on 2 places.

Comment: OK can you specify some more information, like which wallet software you are using, what EXACTLY did you back-up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your backup file of %appdata%/bitcoin/wallet.dat
2. Go to your local file of %appdata%/bitcoin/ and delete the wallet.dat
3. Replace the old Wallet.Dat

You should have all your bitcoins back now.